# How to use NEON comparison (greater than or equal to) instruction?

Tags: arm, simd, intrinsics, neon, cortex-a8

How to use the NEON comparison instructions in general?

Here is a case, I want to use, Greater-than-or-equal-to instruction?

Currently I have a,

```
int x;
...
...
...
if(x >= 0)
{
....

}
```

In NEON, I would like to use x in the same way, just that x this time is a vector.

```
int32x4_t x;

...
...
...

if(vcgeq_s32(x, vdupq_n_s32(0))) // Whats the best way to achieve this effect?
{
....

}
```

Comment: I just added a code example at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47320062/how-can-i-vectorize-an-if-block-using-arm-neon-intrinsics/47403867#47403867

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With SIMD it's not straightforward to go from a single scalar if/then to a test on multiple elements. Usually you want to test if *any* element is greater than or if *all* elements are greater than, and there will usually be different SIMD predicates for each case which you can put inside an `if (...)`. I don't see anything like this in NEON though, so you may be out of luck.

Often though you want to take a different approach, since branches are usually not desirable in optimised code. Ideally you will want to use the result of a SIMD comparison as a mask for subsequent operations (e.g. select different values based on mask using bitwise operations).

Comment: Paul, I modified my algorithm, now I have got rid of the branch conditions, so I don't need these if (...) conditions and simply do direct arithmetic operations using SIMD.